# http error 413.1 - request entity too large in .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am getting this error saying

> HTTP Error 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large
>
> The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length

In order to fix this issue, I did the following:

Increased the RequestFormLimits to int.MaxValue in my controller like so:

```
 [RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
```

Added the following code in my startup.cs file:

```
      services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormOptions>(x =>
        {
            x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
            x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue; // In case of multipart
        });
```

Added the following in my web.config file

```
 <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <!-- 2 GB -->
          <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
```

I tried to upload 1 GB file and I am getting an error saying :

> HTTP Error 413.1 - Request Entity Too Large

any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: For what it's worth, `int.MaxValue` is 2 GiB, not 4 (i.e., 2147483647).  I don't know if that's your issue.  I could see a web server request such a huge content length in the interest of rejecting DOS attacks

Comment: Well, the question is - **how** big is the request?

Comment: I changed the config file to this: <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" /> still getting the same error.

Comment: I am trying to upload 1 GB size file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are using .net core 3.1 or lower,try to add the codes in your startup class:

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = 2147483648;
});
```

The official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1#iis-1

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: Does not work for me either

Comment: Does not work for me either, trying to upload 18Mb file